# Use facebook iOS SDK auth token in webview

Tags: ios, facebook, webview, oauth, token

I'm trying to see if I can re-use the facebook access token I'm getting in my iOS app (from the facebook SDK) and pass it to a custom webview (to be logged in to the same app but on the web).

What I have so far:
The app currently authenticated correctly on the mobile device (my App switches to FB App and returns to my App with Token)

```
var accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()
var tokenString = accessToken.tokenString
```

Any help is appreciated, I spent a lot of time looking for a solution but all the clues I found were outdated and deprecated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your question is simply how to pass data from native app to a webview.
You can use js. e.g. Suppose this is the code on your webview which uses the access token saved as `test.html`:

```
    <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            function usesAccessToken(access_token_string) {
             // use access token 
              alert(access_token_string);
            }
            </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

You can pass values to the js function in the following manner:

```
[self.myAppWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

In the `UIWebViewDelegate` delegate method:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSString *accessToken = [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].tokenString;
    NSString *functionToCall = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"usesAccessToken('%@')", accessToken];
    [self.myAppWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:functionToCall];
}
```

Comment: It might be important to note that sharing access tokens in clients is not advisable.